# Help with high limit thermostat replacement on Kenmore 110 series dryer?

Tags: thermostat

My tenant’s dryer stopped heating, and when I took the back off to check the thermal coil the high limit thermostat fell into pieces. Ha, ok. Tested the circuit on the coil just in case and it’s fine. Ordered a new thermostat, came back to install, and wtf why are there only two wires when everything else I see has three? I’m so confused. Can anyone help?
[image]

Comment: Are the two thermostats  the same?  How many wires were on the old one?

Comment: Ugh. Thanks for asking! Turns out this particular model only has two wires (though that info was super hard to find) and I feel stupid now :)

Comment: Most of the dryers I have worked on have thermal fuses when they overheat they blow under 10$ usually make sure the reason for the overheat is cleared. Lint plugged in the pipe can cause a fire and be the reason (plugged exhaust) that the thermal fuse blew.